# riding a pig value

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a mechanism with command blocks so that a player can give a pig a levitating effect only if it is on that pig. I have no idea how to do it, however the minecraft version is 1.15.2.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
/execute as @a at @s if data entity @s RootVehicle run effect give @e[type=pig,distance=..0.4,limit=1,sort=nearest] minecraft:levitation 1 0 true
```

Comment: sorry, and if i want the reversed effect, so when i get off the pig, i want to execute a command

Comment: You can use the same command but invert it by replacing "if" with "unless".